# Difference between argparse.Namespace and types.SimpleNamespace?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It seems they both behave exactly the same – both are like `dicts` but with `.` literal to access an item, however none of it is even a subclass of another

```
from argparse import Namespace
from types import SimpleNamespace

issubclass(Namespace, SimpleNamespace)  # False
issubclass(SimpleNamespace, Namespace)  # False
```

So, are there any differences between them two?
Can `argparse.Namespace` be used in all cases?

Comment: There is no reason to suppose they are related classes. They have the same obvious syntax but serve different purposes. `argparse` is specific to a particular purpose. `types` is about as general as it is possible to be. As you can discover from reading the documentation, `argparse` was written to address what its developers considered design flaws in its predecessor `optparse`, which also had a `Namespace` class, and I believe that `optparse` predated `types.SimpleNamespace`.

Comment: "Can argparse.Namespace be used in all cases?" I think that's the wrong question to ask, frankly. The reason why you might want to have two seperate *types* with for all practical purposes the same functionality is the same reason why you would want to use different `enum`s instead of just magical `int`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There once [was a proposal to have the `argparse` inherit](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/83257). That said, just use the `types` one if you are using a new enough Python; that's what it is there for.

Comment: The current issue link is: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/83257

Comment: So the self-contained answer is: they are two independent implementations of the same thing with a few minor technical differences that would not warrant a merger, but maintainers did not bother merging them.